# Filtering out objects according to their fields in a GORM query

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'm new at grails and stuck with a performance issue. 
I have three domain classes:

```
User{
Set authorities
static hasMany = [authorities: Role]
}

Organization{
//more code
}

UserOrganization{
User user
Organization organization
}
```

there are many roles (authorities) assigned to a user ('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_MANAGER')

In one scenario I have a list of organization and I need to find out all the users with manager authority (ROLE_MANAGER) of these organizations.

I tried using GORM like this:

```
UserOrganization.createCriteria().list{
inList('organizaton',organizationList)
//but do not know how to filter out users with ROLE_MANAGER authority
}
```

Is there any way to get it done in single GORM query like this? 
I could get the list of all the Users of these organizations and run retainAll{closure} to filter out the managers but that would be a two step process and create a performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

```
UserOrganization.createCriteria().list{
    inList('organizaton',organizationList)
    user {
        inList('authorities',authoritiesList)
    }
}
```

Btw. you don't need explicitly write `authorities` GORM will create it for you:

```
User {
    static hasMany = [authorities: Role]
}
```

In case you want to ensure that authorities will be of `Set` or other collection type, you should then write: `Set authorities`